# Stuck in bootloop

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

hie there.
I'm new with this so please bear with me I'm not used with the terminology
I have a SA Swag Tab 103 it was freezing most of the time so l did a normal rest(setting-restore) during the boot it said ERROR and it restarted itself and went to stuck on the animation log(bootloop) .
Ever since I have been searching for a solution/s .
its RAM is  1GB
OS ICS
Processor 1GHz 
PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

Bootloops are always fun... Fortunately they are also (in most circumstances) fairly easy to fix, however this process will reset *ALL* of the data on your device.

Start your device in Fast-boot. This varies per device, but it is almost always holding the power button and either volume up buttons or volume down buttons for 4 seconds, then releasing, just as you would normally turn on the device but with an extra button. You'll come up with a very barebones looking interface. Figure out how to scroll through this option page (your touch screen is off. This is 100% volume and power buttons here) and select factory reset. (selection is usually the power button or up button) If factory reset is missing, things become complicated. Open recovery and press and hold the same buttons that got the device into the fast boot menu when you see the dead android, then release just like earlier. Another set of options will hopefully come up. Select factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

When experimenting a lot with Android you have a a pretty high chance of getting a **bootloop** once, but also if you install an other **rom** and still use the **dalvik-cache** of the previous **rom**.
When you have a bootloop, you will notice that the boot process of your phone keeps looping and looping. And it will never stop until you fix the bootloop!


Bootloops can occur pretty easily,  it’s mainly caused because system files interfering with each other which causes instability and/or crashes at the boot sequence.
Think of system apps that are compiled incorrectly, permissions that are not set correctly, files from other devices and even an init.d script, everything is possible.
The way I solved the problem is using SP flash tool and stock ROM.

1.) Firstly the windows won't be able to recognize the smartphone so in that case you have to install **USB drivers** based on your manufacturer .

2.)Now **POWER OFF** the device and remove the battery.

3.)Download the **stock** ROM for flashing purpose on the android and also download **SP FLASH TOOL** and extract it.

4.)Next, run the **Flash_tool.exe** in the extracted folder .

5.)Once,the SP flash tool is launched click on the **Download** tab

6.)Next, select the **scattered file** from the location of the extracted stock **ROM** .

7.)Then click on the **DOWNLOAD** button to start the **flashing ** process .

8.)BOOM ! you have overwritten the wrong **permissions** in the system image file by flashing a new updated **STOCK ROM**.

Now, the boot loading will work
**reminder** : before starting the process , at **boot** press and hold both volume buttons + power button,then click on the **volume up** button.

It will show a dead icon of android, then just hold powerbutton and the menu button .Next thing appears would be a list under android recovery  .

There click on the **wipe dalvik cache partition** and the reboot.After then take out the  phone battery.